# socket programming learning

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, ip

I have been learning how to program sockets, but when I try practice writing codes, I have some problems. The code works for connecting to computers on the same LAN but when I try to connect to two computers on a different network over the internet, I was unable to.

Is this because of the program or is this because of network security?

Where can I find more information on it if I want to make applications communicate over the internet. I was thinking of making a chat program so that I understanding it better but I can't even make the program communicate over the internet!

Edit:
Well the port that i am using is 6892. It's just a random port. i'm stil kinda learning these things.

Comment: The crystal ball is hazy today. Please show some code or at least some details about the ports you are using, your network settings, etc.

Comment: You should keep in mind, that most ports on the internet are blocked by firewalls, so try to connect two hosts where you are able to control these.

Comment: but how do you get through the firewall? like how common chat applications today would have to get through the firewall right?

Comment: firstly, check if 6892 on the remote computer is accessible from your computer. `telnet REMOTE_IP 6892`

Answer (score 3):

If you're using native sockets, and you're behind a firewall, this will definitely fail.  Your firewall will almost certainly be set to only allow port 80, for http, and port 443 (?) for https.

Comment: so does this mean that i have to open a port on the firewall or do some sort of port forwarding?

Comment: I'd avoid opening any unnecessary ports, especially if you're not sure what you're doing.  That's a surefire way of getting hacked.  But yes, you can do that.  List of standard ports are here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers

As Clyfe comment below mentions, you might not even be able to connect, even if you did have the right ports open.  You could consider http tunnelling, for example.

Comment: You'll need to open up the port that you're using on any firewall between the two ends of the socket link.

Comment: well understand that opening ports are risky but how to programs that connect to the internet access the internet? for http tunnelling, do i have write another set of codes? would it be safe to hard code the ip into the program?

Answer (score 2):

In some Layer 3 network topologies connections between computers is not bidirectional, and one has to mediate communication via techniques like a federation broker.

A remote station may not address your computer directly, he can only reach up to your gateway, depending on the setup.

Answer (score 0):

Is one or both or your computers in a local network? If they have IPs starting with `192.168`, they are in a local network.

You can also use http://whatismyipaddress.com/ to check whether the IP displayed is the same with the IP you see on your computers, but remember to remove any proxies.

If the destination computer is in a local network, or the IP displayed in the said website different from what is seen on the computer, you will have a problem. This situation would have nothing to do with your program, but you'll have to configure your networks. You may have to contact your network manager to resolve it.

Comment: yes when both computers are in are local network they are able to communicate. but when they are not on the same the program cannot communicate. That is what i am trying to understand: how to make them communicate when they are not on the same network.

Comment: @mma1480 This is because local network address cannot be seen outside the network. You need to know what address is used to access the local network (usually is the one shown in the said website), and you'll need port forwarding. Maybe this can help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding . But configuring net forwarding need administrative privilege to managed the configuration of the local network. You may have to contact your network manager.